# Отправка образа на docker hub

Tags: docker

Есть образ объемом 10 гб, 9.5 из 10 занимает слой с библиотеками и моделями и 0.5 гб само приложение. На локальном компе 9.5 гб слой берется из кеша и перезаписываются только последние 0.5 гб. А как происходит заливка на docker hub? Он будет все 10 гб каждый раз заливать или как git hub только 0.5 гб изменений? ДУмаю стоит ли заливать каждый раз с локального компьютера образ или на сервер только код отправлять и там собирать.